# jQuery Timepicker - prevent pop-up when field is readonly

Tags: jquery, html, timepicker

I have this code...

HTML

```
<input name="start_time" id="start_time" type="text" value="" readonly >
```

JQuery

```
$('#start_time').timepicker({
    showPeriodLabels: true,
    minutes: {
        starts: 0,
        ends: 59,
        interval: 1,
        manual: []
    }
});
```

Display
[image]

**Problem:**

 - Timepicker still pops-up considering the field is 'readonly'.
 - How can I prevent this?
 - Any other work around?

Thank you guys for all the help!

Comment: Making the field readonly is the usual way to force the user to use the datepicker, instead of typing directly into the input field.

Comment: If you want to prevent them from filling in the field at all, you should disable it instead of making it readonly.

Comment: @Barmar i can't get the value if I use disable.

Comment: Why do you have the datepicker on the field if it's supposed to be readonly?

Comment: this is both on my insert/edit page.. so I am planning to put a variable inside to indicate if field is readonly or not. ex: for insert, $editable=''; for edit, $editable='readonly';  <input name="start_time" id="start_time" type="text" value="" <?php echo $editable;?> />

Comment: @Barmar I get your point. I could use a label to display this. But is there no other way to prevent timepicker to pop-up when readonly? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check before that your input box have readonly property or not then apply the timepicker on that. Go with the link or below code. Hope my code helps you to understand better.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91n23Lz/117/)

HTML Code-

```
<input name="start_time" id="start_time" type="text" value="" readonly >
```

JAVASCRIPT Code-

```
if(!$('#start_time').prop('readonly')){
  $('#start_time').timepicker({
      showPeriodLabels: true,
      minutes: {
          starts: 0,
          ends: 59,
          interval: 1,
          manual: []
      }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @Jorz My pleasure.